# Java Calculate value with goal seek

Tags: java, android, operators, equation

In the development of an application Android, I have this operation

```
float number1 = 1;
float number2 = 2;
float input_util;

  float  one_operate = input_util * number1 + number2;

  float calPS = input_util - one_operate;
```

`input_util` is entered by user.

Also, how to do if I want user entered `calPS` instead of `input_util`, for calculate `input_util` ?

Is there a goal seek method with java ?

Thanks.

Comment: _how to do if I want user entered calPS instead of input_until for calculate input_until_ This is unclear and hence the question is difficult to understand I'm afraid.

Comment: I'm sorry for my very bad english, I'm french. My question is simply whether there is a method to find `input_util` if the user entered `calPS` ?

Comment: There is such a method, its called mathematics.

Comment: Like @Okas mentioned, there isn't one. You have to program that logic.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answers. The sequence of calculations in my application is much more complex then I was wondering if there was not a method of the same type as the goalseek function under Excel.

Answer (score 0):

```
float number1 = 1;
float number2 = 2;
float input_util;

input_util=Float.parseFloat(yourEditText.getText.toString);

float  one_operate = input_util * number1 + number2;

float calPS = input_util - one_operate;
```

Comment: thank you, but I know how to recover the input of the user. My question is simply whether there is a method to find `input_util` if the user entered only `calPS` ?